# tcplay: cannot write to mounted volume

Tags: linux, mount, truecrypt

#### Background

I set up a TrueCrypt volume in Windows that I want to write to in Linux. It is a file within a hard drive I have mounted to a directory: `drwx------  1 user user  20K Aug 18 02:53 hdd/`. I also tried from a local copy of the file. I ran the following commands and was able to read from it, but could not chmod or write to it as root.

```
user@PC:~$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/volume/file
user@PC:~$ sudo tcplay -d /dev/loop0 -m tcvol
user@PC:~$ sudo mkdir /media/user/tcvol
user@PC:~$ sudo chown user /media/user/tcvol
user@PC:~$ sudo chmod 777 /media/user/tcvol
user@PC:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/tcvol /media/user/tcvol
user@PC:~$ sudo cat /media/user/tcvol/somefile
some contents
user@PC:~$ sudo echo "hello world" > /media/user/tcvol/test.txt
bash: /media/user/tcvol/test.txt: Permission denied
```

At this point, I can read from the volume, but I cannot chmod or write to any volume contents even as root. `chmod 777 -R /media/user/tcvol` has no output and does not change permissions; same goes for `chown`. `ll` produces output like the following:

```
user@PC:~$ ll /media/user/tcvol
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   12 Jul 28 10:06 somefile
```

#### Question

I am somehow unable to write to this volume after mounting it. What is going wrong?

#### Further Details

```
user@PC:~$ sudo tcplay -d /dev/loop0 -i
Device:         /dev/loop0
PBKDF2 PRF:     whirlpool
PBKDF2 iterations:  1000
Cipher:         SERPENT-256-XTS
Key Length:     512 bits
CRC Key Data:       0x494f9a81
Sector size:        512
Volume size:        1536 sectors
IV offset:      256
Block offset:       256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Since there are only 2 other questions about tcplay and neither address this particular problem, I have decided to share my findings. Without further adieu, my answer:

```
user@PC:~$ vim /media/user/tcvol/newfile.txt
(i "hello world" esc :wq)
user@PC:~$ cat /media/user/tcvol/newfile.txt
hello world
```

The writing issue was the echo command, though I am unsure why chmod did not work. After a lot of faffing about. I created a [script for mounting and unmounting TrueCrypt volumes](https://pastebin.com/G0AZN4VX) as a normal user. I wrote it to `/usr/bin/tcmount` and chmodded it to 755. The most notable change is this:

```
user@PS:~$ sudo mount -o uid=`id -u` /dev/loopX /media/user/whatever
```

The `-o uid` flag ensures that the user account has rwx access to the mounted volume. Hopefully someone will find this useful.

Edit: I moved the script contents to a pastebin paste. It was cluttering up the answer too much.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for this answer, amidst all the mega truecrypt-replacement software out there, this simple script worked most reliably for me. I've added this as a github repo (with credits), hope you don't mind: https://github.com/digital-carver/tcmount

Comment: +sundar awesome. I've worked on a couple of improvements for the script, but I haven't finalized them; I'll make a pull request when they are done.